# Error al cargar items en net core 5.0 mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-core

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en net core usando mvc, me encuentro con un error al cargar unos datos de una columna de una base de datos en  un DropDownList pero al momento de cargar la lista me aparece me arroja una excepción que detallo a continuación.

> Excepción producida: 'System.InvalidOperationException' en Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll

El código que produce esta excepción es el siguiente.

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetRoles(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selectListItems= null;
        try
        {
            selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var rol = roleManager.Roles.ToList();
            rol.ForEach(item =>
            {
                selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = item.Id,
                    Text = item.Name
                });
            });                
        }            
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: '{ex}'");
        }
        return selectListItems;
        
    }
```

De antemano les agradezco su ayuda.